# Avoiding code duplication for attribute-removal code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use the same code in different jQuery attributes.  Is it possible to put this if in a external function and call it inside a change event?  I would like avoid duplicating code.

```
$("#Max").change(function () {
var max = $("#Max").val();
var min = $("#Min").val();

if (max != min) {
    $("#Result").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
else {
    $("#Result").removeAttr("disabled");
}
});

$("#Min").change(function () {
var max = $("#Max").val();
var min = $("#Min").val();

if (max != min) {
    $("#Result").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
else {
    $("#Result").removeAttr("disabled");
}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can either assign the function to a variable or name it. You can further clean it up (slightly) by storing the jQuery selectors. Finally, I've wrapped it all up in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to avoid polluting the global space.

```
(function () {
    var $max = $("#Max"),
        $min = $("#Min"),
        $result = $("#Result"),
        changeHandler = function () {
            var max = $max.val(),
                min = $min.val();

            if (max != min) {
                $result.attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
            else {
                $result.removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        };

    $max.change(changeHandler);
    $min.change(changeHandler);
}());
```

Answer (score 7):

I think that @david-harkness code could be simplified further:

```
(function () {
    var $max = $("#Max"),
        $min = $("#Min"),
        $result = $("#Result"),
        changeHandler = function () {
            $result.prop("disabled", $max.val() != $min.val());
        };

    $max.change(changeHandler);
    $min.change(changeHandler);
}());
```

but I'm not really sure about the side effects of using prop instead of attr.

Comment: In the case of `disabled`, `.prop()` is actually preferred. You'll want to be keen on the differences of `.prop()` and `.attr()` when dealing with stuff like `src`, `href`, and other things that are parsed by the browser instead of left as-is.

Comment: If you are going for performance, why not do `$result[0].disabled = $max.val() != $min.val()` ?

Comment: Wow, I had no idea about the distinction between attributes and properties. I highly recommend this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) and "Attributes vs. Properties" on [`jQuery.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)